# Interactjs resizable feature in Angular 4 (ts file)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interact.js

I am using interact in Angular 4.

My draggable function works perfectly.

In my resizable method the event cannot supply me any object property apart from `currentTarget` and `target`.

In the example at http://interactjs.io/#resizing:

```
var target = event.target,

x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

// update the element's style
target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

// translate when resizing from top or left edges
x += event.deltaRect.left;
y += event.deltaRect.top;
```

`event.rect` and `event.deltaRect` cannot be reached. It says that `Property event.rect` and `event.deltaRect` are not the type of `InteractEvent.`

**Question**
Why this is happening?

---

The whole code is:

```
let msgFrontX,
  msgFrontY,
  imgFrontX,
  imgFrontY,
  msgBackX,
  msgBackY,
  imgBackX,
  imgBackY;
interact('.resize-drag')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 1,
        right: 1
      }
    },
    // enable autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,
    onstart: function (event) {},
    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    // call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      const parentContainer = event.currentTarget.offsetParent;
      const elem = event.currentTarget;

      function percentageCalc(direction) {
        if (direction === 'horizontal') {
          return event.clientX0 / event.clientX 100;
        } else {
          return event.clientY0 / event.clientY 100;
        }
      }
      if (parentContainer.classList.contains('front')) {
        if (elem.classList.contains('msg-container')) {
          msgFrontX = percentageCalc('horizontal');
          msgFrontY = percentageCalc('vertical');
        } else {
          imgFrontX = percentageCalc('horizontal');
          imgFrontY = percentageCalc('vertical');
        }
      } else {
        if (elem.classList.contains('msg-container')) {
          msgBackX = percentageCalc('horizontal');
          msgBackY = percentageCalc('vertical');
        } else {
          imgBackX = percentageCalc('horizontal');
          imgBackY = percentageCalc('vertical');
        }
      }
      that.setPositions(msgFrontX, msgFrontY, imgFrontX, imgFrontY,
        msgBackX, msgBackY, imgBackX, imgBackY);
    }
  }).resizable({
    edges: {
      left: true,
      right: true,
      bottom: true,
      top: true
    },
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 1,
        right: 1
      }
    }
  }).on('resizeend', function (event) {
    console.log(event.resizeRects);
    var target = event.target,
      x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
      y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

    // update the element's style
    target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);

  });

function dragMoveListener(event) {
  const target = event.target,
    // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
    x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
    y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
  // translate the element
  target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
    'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
  // update the position attributes
  target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
  target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
}
```

**Error in console**

```
ERROR in C:/Users/usuario/Documents/sitios/tshirtCustom/src/app/customizer/customizer.component.ts (325,34): Property 'rect' does not exist on type 'InteractEvent'.
ERROR in C:/Users/usuario/Documents/sitios/tshirtCustom/src/app/customizer/customizer.component.ts (326,35): Property 'rect' does not exist on type 'InteractEvent'.
ERROR in C:/Users/usuario/Documents/sitios/tshirtCustom/src/app/customizer/customizer.component.ts (329,18): Property 'deltaRect' does not exist on type 'InteractEvent'.
ERROR in C:/Users/usuario/Documents/sitios/tshirtCustom/src/app/customizer/customizer.component.ts (330,18): Property 'deltaRect' does not exist on type 'InteractEvent'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The InteractEvent interface does not have rect and deltaRect. You can check that in ..\node_modules\interactjs\index.d.ts

This is probably because of different versions in production and sample code.

But there is a work around.

```
.on('resizeend', function (ev) {
   const event = <any> ev;
   console.log(event.resizeRects);
   var target = event.target,
   x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
   y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

   //......
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it does not work that. ERROR in src/app/customizer/customizer.component.ts(318,9): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ edges: { left: boolean; right: boolean; bottom: boolean; top: boolean; }; restrictEdges: { oute...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ResizableOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'restrictEdges' does not exist in type 'ResizableOptions'.

Comment: that is a different issue, you can remove edges and restrictEdges

Answer (score 0):

As Aatish mentioned previously there there is an issue on ../node_modules\interactjs\index.d.ts, the ts is not having the proper exposed properties, so a colleague of mine recommended to add it to  the ts and the problem was solved